# How can I call a function of an element returned as an ElementHandle?

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I can make a change to a property and trigger a re-render of an element on this page via the console

Open JBrowse demo site via [this link](http://jbrowse.org/code/JBrowse-1.12.4/?loc=ctgA%3A16801..23754&tracks=volvox-sorted_bam&data=sample_data%2Fjson%2Fvolvox&nav=0&tracklist=0&fullviewlink=0&highlight=) then read on...

In console I can run the following to update 1 element (in reality I'd do them all):

```
document.querySelectorAll('.track_jbrowse_view_track_alignments2')[0].track.displayMode = 'compact'
document.querySelectorAll('.track_jbrowse_view_track_alignments2')[0].track.layout = null
document.querySelectorAll('.track_jbrowse_view_track_alignments2')[0].track.redraw()
```

I'm attempting to perform this in the puppeteer code with:

```
const tracks = await page.$$('.track_jbrowse_view_track_alignments2');
for (let t of tracks) {
  await page.evaluate(t => {
    t.displayMode = 'compact';
    t.layout = null;
    t.redraw();
  }, t);
}
```

The existing functional script is under [this link](https://github.com/cancerit/cgpJBrowseToolkit/blob/31ecb7a86666c8b782a8d7ebebe1235a5d1eaf3a/js/jbrowse_rasterize.js#L193), the above snippet would be inserted immediately following the highlighted line.

Any guidance would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should wait for your JS code when it is fully ready. It's up to you how you detect it, I just use dummy `await page.waitFor(10000);`. Next, you should invoke your operation on `t.track` object not on `t`.

Here is working example:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto(
    'http://jbrowse.org/code/JBrowse-1.12.4/?loc=ctgA%3A16801..23754&tracks=volvox-sorted_bam&data=sample_data%2Fjson%2Fvolvox&nav=0&tracklist=0&fullviewlink=0&highlight='
  );

  await page.waitFor(10000);

  const tracks = await page.$$('.track_jbrowse_view_track_alignments2');
  for (let t of tracks) {
    await page.evaluate(t => {
      t.track.displayMode = 'compact';
      t.track.layout = null;
      t.track.redraw();
    }, t);
  }
  await page.screenshot({ path: 'image.png' });
  await browser.close();
})();
```

Comment: Thanks, turns out what I had worked if I put it in a slightly different location.  I'd already set the goto to be using `waitUntil: ['load', 'domcontentloaded', 'networkidle0']`